# Reporting focal strain (high MI) for CFA models with good model fit?

Tags: interpretation, goodness-of-fit, confirmatory-factor, reporting

According to Brown (2015), one is expected to examine and report localized areas of ill fit (e.g. modification indices (MI)) as part of the model evaluation. I have a number of questions about reporting and examining the MI’s given the following scenario

1. Overall fit of the model being tested in CFA is good according to CFI,
   TLI, S-RMR, RMSEA
2. However, there are simply too many modification indices that exceed the 
   value of 10 (about the same number as the total number of indicators). For the 
   most part, these pertained to error covariances of items that load onto the 
   same latent variables. Therefore, it is not easy to dismiss the large MI 
   values on the basis of substantive reasons.

Questions are:

1. How do you interpret so many indicators of poor local fit in the presence of
   good overall model fit?
2. Are you expected to report AND address "focal strains"?

Reference
Brown, Timothy A. Confirmatory factor analysis for applied research. Guilford 
 Publications, 2015.

Comment: What's your sample size?

Comment: Sample size is approx. 700.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about MIs of 10 in a sample size of 100. Look at the standardized expected parameter change (SEPC). Is that big enough to worry about?

Comment: Thank you for your response. SEPC for the largest MI values (>20-45) range from -.17 to .17. These are for approx. 30% of the indicators. I do not have a good sense of how these indicators generally relate to the sample size (n=700) though I did note from text that more ill fit is likely to occur with larger samples.

Comment: They're not huge, but they are moderate. If your fit is good, I wouldn't worry.

Comment: Upvotes for answer appreciated.

Comment: I remain curious about the second part of my question, which concerns the proper reporting of these results. I suppose some may choose not to draw attention to the focal strain, especially when there is no need to make changes to the model to improve the model fit. My reading of a few studies has been that studies often have various reasons for minimizing the local ill fit.

Comment: I'm not sure what a focal strain is. I've not heard that term used in CFA.

Comment: Focal strain or localized areas of strain in solution were terms used in the above referenced text (Brown, 2015): "localized areas of ill fit" indicated by (modification indices/Lagrange multipliers, standardized residuals, etc). The following study by the author also provides an example: Rosellini, Anthony J., and Timothy A. Brown. "The NEO Five-Factor Inventory: latent structure and relationships with dimensions of anxiety and depressive disorders in a large clinical sample." Assessment 18.1 (2011): 27-38.

Comment: Typing <"focal strain" cfa> into Google gives me three questions from you on Crossvalidated, and seven links about bacteria. Typing <"modification index" cfa> gives me about 10k links, the tenth of which is the book you cite.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40346/discussion-between-jeremy-miles-and-user81715).